# Flutter: Snapshot is not updating its data

Tags: flutter

So I'm trying to save data into firestore, but I have a class to signup which has this code:

```
FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
        await auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
            email: emailController.text, password: passwordController.text)
            .then((value) => {
          Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'DialogFlow'),
          user=auth.currentUser,
          user.sendEmailVerification(),
          DatabaseService(uid:user.uid).UpdateUserData("", emailController.text, ChatScreenState().mess)
```

this will navigate me to the dialogflow, which has this code:

```
    @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
         final firebaseUser = context.watch<User>();
            FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
            user=auth.currentUser;
              DatabaseService db = DatabaseService(uid: user.uid);
return StreamBuilder(
        stream: db.userData,
        builder: (context , snapshot){
          Userdata userdata=snapshot.data;
          print("====================================");
          print(snapshot.data);
          print("====================================");
          if (userdata != null) {
            this.userTestMessage = "";
            shhh = pressed ? true : false;
            flag = true;
            if (!Retrieved_messages) {
              this.messsages = userdata.messsages; //Retrieve user data from firebase only once.
              // Retrieve user data from firebase only once.
              Retrieved_messages = true;
            }//load only 20 messages at once . When we scroll up load more.
              db.UpdateUserData(
                firebaseUser.displayName, firebaseUser.email, this.messsages);
            print(userdata.messsages);
            print(mess);
            print(userdata.messsages);
            print("==============================");
            print(snapshot.data);
            print("==============================");
          }
          if (db.getUserMessages() == null) {
            if (firebaseUser != null) {
              db.UpdateUserData(
                  firebaseUser.displayName, firebaseUser.email, this.messsages);
            }
          }
```

and the database class is

```
    DatabaseService({this.uid, this.messsages});

  final CollectionReference userCollection = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('users');

  UpdateUserData(String Username, String Email,
      List messsages) async
  { try {
    return await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").doc(uid).set({
      'Username': Username,
      'Email': Email,
      'messsages': messsages,

    }
    );
  }catch(e){
    print(e+" this is the error");
  }
  }


  Future getUserMessages() async
  {
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(uid).snapshots();
  }


  Userdata _userDataFromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
    return Userdata(uid: uid,
        name: snapshot.data()['Username'],
        email: snapshot.data()['Email'],
        messsages: snapshot.data()['messsages']
    );
  }

  Stream<Userdata> get userData {
    return userCollection.doc(uid).snapshots().map(_userDataFromSnapshot);
  }


}
```

The problem I'm facing is that whenever I create a new user, and try to save new messages, the firestore keeps on saving and removing the messages, so its in an infinite loop, so I hope that someone can tell me how I can fix it that it saves the messages without removing them.

Note: the snapshot data isn't updating.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the reason you have your build function rebuilt is usage of `context.watch` in the beginning of your build(). As in bloc [documentation](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/migration?id=packageflutter_bloc-1):

> Using context.watch at the root of the build method will result in the entire widget being rebuilt when the bloc state changes. If the entire widget does not need to be rebuilt, either use BlocBuilder to wrap the parts that should rebuild, use a Builder with context.watch to scope the rebuilds, or decompose the widget into smaller widgets.